# Need access to views on the OnSeekBarChangeListener (which is in an own class)

Tags: android, view

First of all, I hope you understand my English, because I'am not a native speaker.

Okay, I am new to Android development and I'm trying following for in app: I need a `SeekBar`, so I created a `Seekbar` via XML and implemented an `OnSeekBarChangeListener`.

In the company I work for, it's forbidden (because of the `styleguid`) to create something like this:

```
seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() 
{
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int arg1, boolean arg2) 
{
    /// Do something       
}
...
});
```

So I need to create my own class for the `OnSeekBarChangeListener`. So far no problem.

```
public class SeekBarChangeListener extends OnSeekBarChangeListener
{
public SeekBarChangeListener(Context context) 
{
    super(context);
}

public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) 
{
}

public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) 
{
}

public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) 
{
/// Do something. Following Code wont work
CheckBox RemeberUsername = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.RemeberUsername);
/// Always gets NULL
}
}
```

I need a way to get access to some controls. Normally, the `findViewById` works fine, but not in this case: something that I can totally understand, because how should the listener know about the views?

Do you have good hints?

Or is there no other way like the first code snippet to get the controls?

Hope someone can help me out.

Comment: Exactly what you want do, can you explain me?

Comment: I will use the slider to show some more options or not. SeekBar can only be 0 oder max (handeld by the Listener) and if the Seekbar is 0 some checkboxes will not be availible (because they dont make sense then). If the SeekBar is max the checkboxes should be availible. Hope its Exactly engouh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the constructor for that listener you already have a reference to a `Context`, most probably the `Activity` where you created the `Spinner`(if you pass `this`(in the activity) when you instantiate the listener) so cast your `Context` from the constructor to that `Activity` and use `findViewById()` on that context:

**Edit:**

Your implementing the listener the wrong way, right now you are extending the `SeekBar` widget class(?!?!) and then implementing the listener interface. The listener class should be like this:

```
public class SeekChanged implements OnSeekBarChangeListener {

    private Context context;

    public SeekChanged(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
            boolean fromUser) {}

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        SeekBarListener activity = (SeekBarListener) context;
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) activity.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        cb.setText("Not null");
    }

}
```

Then in the activity(I named my activity `SeekBarListener`) with the layout containing the `SeekBar`:

```
//...
SeekBar sb = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
sb.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekChanged(this));
//...
```

Comment: Throws a java.lang.ClassCastException :/ Update code in the question

Comment: @sandkasten See my edited answer, I didn't see that you extend `SeekBar`(why are you doing this?).